# qooxdoo: SetValue always fires changeValue first time

Tags: qooxdoo

In qooxdoo a setValue will always fire a 'changeValue' event even when passing '' or null.
Is this a bug or do I have to add a model to the controller first before adding listeners?

```
var field = new qx.ui.mobile.form.PasswordField();
field.addListener('changeValue', function () {
    alert('changed');
});
field.setValue(''); //results in onchange
field.setValue(null); //results in onchange
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing that up. This seems like a bug to me. You can also do the following thing:

field.setValue(field.getValue());

which should never lead to a change event. Could you open up a bug report here: http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/

Comment: field.setValue(field.getValue()); also fails indeed.
Logged bug http://bugs.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7612
Thanks